# How to watch for partials change in devserver webpack5?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, html-webpack-plugin

I am using webpack-dev-server with hot:true and use partials in templateParameters for HTML-webpack-plugin, HMR works fine when I change one of pages, but it doesn't when I change one of partials. How can I make dev-server to watch for some files constantly in every HTML file? Like if I change header.html then it will refresh every page displayed. Or the better one solution would be if somehow I can add dependencies for my HTML files to watch. I tried to add WatchPartials class from here https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/1929, but it doesn't work.

My Partials, that will be added to templateParameters:

```
const PARTIALS = {}
fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname,'src','partials')).forEach((file) => {
    PARTIALS[file.replace(/.html/,'')] = fs.readFileSync(`./src/partials/${file}`,{encoding:'utf-8'})
})
```

My HtmlWebpackPlugin config:

```
plugins:[
    ...PAGES.map(page => new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template:`${PAGES_DIR}/${page}`,
        templateParameters:{
            PARTIALS
        },
        filename:`./${page}`,
        chunks:[page.replace(/\.html/,'')],
        minify:{
            collapseWhitespace:isProd
        }
    })),
```

and devserver config:

```
devServer:{
    port:4200,
    compress:true,
    hot:true,
    watchFiles:['src/**/*.html'],
},
```

and I call partial in html like this:

```
<%= PARTIALS.header %>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <main class="main">
            <div class="wrapper"><h1>Webpacks</h1></div>
            <div class="logo"></div>
            <div class="card"><h2>SCSS</h2></div>
        </main>
<%= PARTIALS.footer %>
```

Is that possible to make dev-server to watch partials without usage of partials plugins like Handlebars?

Answer (score 0):

This is discussed in:

- https://github.com/colbyfayock/html-webpack-partials-plugin/issues/15
- https://github.com/colbyfayock/html-webpack-partials-plugin/issues/33
- https://github.com/pigcan/extra-watch-webpack-plugin

I was able to get halfway there, requires a browser refresh after each save but at least `webpack-dev-server` builds the file instead of having to restart the dev server and wait for it to compile. I suspect the source map breaks which then requires the page refresh to update the content.

`npm i -D extra-watch-webpack-plugin`

```
const ExtraWatchWebpackPlugin = require('extra-watch-webpack-plugin');
const Path                    = require("path");

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new ExtraWatchWebpackPlugin({ // This watches for changes to template partials, but requires browser refresh
      dirs: Path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    }),
  ],
}
```